# Why am I getting NoMethodError for this devise_group call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise 3.5.2, ruby 2.2.2, rails 4.2.3

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  devise_group :user, contains: [:manager, :employee]
end
```

My understanding is that Devise should load [these helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb) automatically and I should be able to use them in ApplicationController without doing anything special.

I try and run the app with 'rails s' and I get this error:

> multi-user-role-devise/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in
>   `<class:ApplicationController>': undefined method`devise_group' for
>   ApplicationController:Class (NoMethodError)   from
>   /home/me/ror-code/multi-user-role-devise/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in
>   `' ....etc

How can I fix this?

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.2'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'devise'
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
```

Manager class:

```
class Manager < User
end
```

Employee class:

```
class Employee < User
end
```

Comment: I'm currently looking at why the tests pass, which test devise_group in the devise gem. Clearly something is including the helpers.rb file there but not in my app, for some reason.

Comment: I've raised this as an issue with the developers. I believe it's a bug with devise but please don't let that stop you trying to answer the question / fix the bug. issue: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3757

Comment: Did you redefine `config.parent_controller` in Devise initializer?

Comment: I didn't. I just noticed they did this in the unit tests for devise. I've tried setting this to 'ApplicationController' but it still gave the same no method error. However, when I move the devise_group statement to other controllers, it works as expected (without setting parent_controller).

Comment: Can you please post your `Gemfile` and your `Manager`, `Employee` models (the devise section in them)

Comment: I will add them above. The manager and employee classes are empty right now, except for the inheritance '<' bit.

Comment: What is this ActionController?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say 'ApplicationController'.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I get the same error when starting the server with the `devise_group` method, however if I comment that line out before the server starts and then uncomment it after things are up and running.......it works as expected. Perhaps this is some kind of error related to the sequence of loading/code inclusion at the application start?

Comment: Can you try adding `include Devise::Controllers::Helpers::ClassMethods` to `ApplicationController` ?

Comment: I think you need to add `include Devise::Controllers::Helpers` line to your `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 0):

If you read through this [Devise issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3757) you will find people with the same problem. At the end, you will find out, that a possible `devise_permitted_parameters.rb` initializer prevents the correct loading of all Devise helpers. By removing this initializer and sanitizing your parameters within your controller should solve the problem.

In the meanwhile, you can add `include Devise::Controllers::Helpers::ClassMethods` within your `ApplicationController` but you should avoid coding style like this in general.